# session.update not updating in db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp page i which i am sending a model attribute from controller and after that making some changes in the properties of model attribute. it is reflecting the model attribute but not updating in database. My code is -

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vc.teacher" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


<!-- Configuration defining views files -->

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
</bean>



<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.vc.teacher.entities.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <!--  <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**AccountContoller class**

```
package com.vc.teacher.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.vc.teacher.db.dao.UserDao;
import com.vc.teacher.entities.User;

@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginUser(@RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("password") String password, Model model) {

        User user = userDao.checkCreditionals(
                email, password);
        if (user != null) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            System.out.println("id=============================="+user.getId());
            return "jsp/profile";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Wrong creditionals");
            return "jsp/signin";
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping("/signUp")
    public String initilize(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new User());
        return "jsp/signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register")
    public String signUpUser(User user, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        boolean result = false;


        user.setStatus("Deactive");
        result = userDao.registerUser(user);

        if (result == true) {
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "You are ready to go now !");
            return "redirect:/signUp";
        } else {
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Something went wrong");
            return "redirect:/signUp";
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/update")
    public String updateUser(User user, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        boolean result = false;

        System.out.println("====================================================="+user.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("============================================="+user.getEmail());
        System.out.println("============================================"+user.getId());

        user.setStatus("Active");
        result = userDao.updateUser(user);

        if (result == true) {
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Profile Updated !");
            return "jsp/profile";
        } else {
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Something went wrong");
            return "jsp/profile";
        }

    }
}
```

**profile.jsp**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-control-material">
                        <sf:input path="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Your first name" value="${user.firstName}" />

                        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-control-material">
                            <sf:input path="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Your last name" value="${user.lastName}" />
                        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-control-material">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <sf:input path="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" value="${user.email}" />
                    <label for="inputEmail3">Email address</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-control-material">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <sf:input path="phone" type="number" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Phone" value="${user.phone}" />
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-control-material">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
                    <sf:input path="address" type="text" class="form-control used" id="website" placeholder="Address" value="${user.address}" />
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Change Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-control-material">
               <sf:input path="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" value="${user.password}" />
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group margin-none">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated>Save Changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</sf:form>
```

**UserDao class**

```
package com.vc.teacher.db.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.vc.teacher.entities.User;

@Component
public class UserDao {


    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public User checkCreditionals(String email, String password){
        User user = null;
        Session session  =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query =   session.createQuery("from User where email = '"+email+"' and password = '"+password+"'");
        List list   =   query.list();
        if(list.size()>0)
            user =  (User)list.get(0);

        return user;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean registerUser(User user){
        boolean result = false;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try{
            user.setUserTypeId(2);
            session.save(user);

            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            result = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean updateUser(User user){
        boolean result = false;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try{
            user.setUserTypeId(2);
            session.update(user);

            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            result = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Here I am login using login method in **AccountController** class and adding a model attribute **user** and making changes in this object in the profile jsp page and after submitting the form its showing changes in the jsp page but not updating the changes in the database. Sometimes this exception also come -

```
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:205)

at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:730)

at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:592)

at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)

at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)

at com.vc.teacher.db.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$467fa027.updateUser(<generated>)

at com.vc.teacher.controller.AccountController.updateUser(AccountController.java:97)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeFor
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my code and i find that my user object was taking id as 0 thats why exception came on updating. I set id on jsp page in the form and that issued my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should first load the user then update user properties.

Your code will like this:

```
 @Transactional
    public boolean updateUser(User user){
        boolean result = false;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try{

            User useToUpdate = session.get(user.getId());

            useToUpdate.setUsername(user.getUsername());

            ...

            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            result = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Hibernate will persist the changes when commiting the transaction, so you don't need to call `session.update(user);`